# Facebook 'share_open_graph' - share dialog in other language

Tags: facebook, knockout.js, share

I have a problem with facebook. I want to share product details (url, image, description) on facebook from a website and everything is in German besides the underlined red words.

[image: red underlined words must be in german]

Here is my code:

[image: typescript function is bind to the viewmodel with knockout.js]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use a click-event to call the function shareButtonTrigger().

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization